# mouseover text appears on all thumbs

Tags: text, mouseover

When I mouse over a thumbnail in Tumblr Archive, thumb goes dark and text appears over it. But something has changed in my settings and ALL thumbs appear like this. I use Win XP and the latest browser is IE8. I don't get this with Firefox or another PC.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me when I updated to IE 10.  It is a compatibility issue.  Go to "tools" and change your "compatibility view" and it will change it back to the normal view (i.e. the thumbnails will show until you mouse over them).  Have one of the archive pages open, and change it, it should update automatically.  If it doesn't fool around with the settings until it changes. You can change the "compatibility view" for "tumblr" only by changing the compatibility view for that site only.